# Pass path from form on button click

Tags: c#

I am using this code to generate the path of a selected file:

```
       private void LoadNewFile()
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    string _xmlPath1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        userSelectedFilePath = ofd.FileName;
    }
}

        private void tbFilePath_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Before i used this code to pass the data:

```
 private void btn_compare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string x1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users", Encoding.UTF8);
```

How do i modify it that instead of x1 that takes the path manually, i need it to be equal to xmlPath1 , so  string x1 = xmlPath1

Comment: Please explain a bit more.

Comment: well, before i just inserted the path of the file manually as you can see, now i take it from a dialog, and i need to assign the x1 variable the path

Comment: Tell me what exactly you want to do on button click ?

Comment: I guess he wants to pass `_xmlPath1` to `btn_compare_Click(...)` to use it there

Comment: on my btn_compare_Click the string x1 should be equal to the path i selected with the dialog opener

Comment: yes, #DMAN, that's what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `_xmlPath1` to a field and you can access it from any method within your class.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected String _xmlPath1;

    ' insert your methods here
}
```

If your methods are not in the same class you have to widen the scope of `_xmlPath1` even more.

EDIT: Changed VB.net syntax to C#

Comment: hmm i'm not understanding where should i insert that code, my methods ar ein the same class

Comment: `MyClass` is just a placeholder for your real class name. Just put the line directly beneath your class definition. For further reading on this topic, have a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1 )If userSelectedFilePath  is a private field you can use it in btn_compare_Click
2 )If it is a local variable ,make it a private field and then see 1
3)Make the the method return the file

```
private string LoadNewFile()
{
   OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
   string _xmlPath1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
   System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
   if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
      return  ofd.FileName;
   else
      return null;

}
```

and use it (you must add validation logic)

```
private void btn_compare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string x1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(LoadNewFile(), Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Option 3 is the best way so you can avoid the extra field and make btn_compare_Click independent from the rest of the code.
In that case you should also give it a better name like GetFileToRead()