# How to make visual studio project into exe file and give UI

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, image-processing

I have a code which detects the **FACES** from the image file (C++ file). I am using **Visual Studio-2010** and **OpenCV-2.4.10** for this project.
Now I want to create an **EXE** file and I want to give **User Interface** which will ask the user to upload an image and produces the Output image back on to the **User Interface**.

So how can I do this.

Please help me in this regards.

Thankz in advance.

Comment: Do you already have the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To build a solution that's open in Visual Studio and selected in Solution Explorer, you can:**

On the menu bar, choose Build, Build Solution.

Or, in Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the solution and then choose Build Solution.

Or, press F7. (This is the default keyboard shortcut for the C/C++ development settings.)

Or, in the Command Window (on the menu bar, choose View, Other Windows, Command Window), enter Build.BuildSolution.

Or, in the Quick Launch box, enter build build solution.

**To build a project that's selected in Solution Explorer, you can:**

On the menu bar, choose Build, Build .

Or, in Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the project and then choose Build.

Or, in the Command Window (on the menu bar, choose View, Other Windows, Command Window), enter Build.BuildOnlyProject.

Or, in the Quick Launch box, enter build project only build only .

You can then navigate to the build location, either /debug or /release depending on the option you have chosen, you will find your .exe there

Comment: Thankz @Dave... I found that... When I doble click on that EXE file, it will show the output image. Thats fine.

Comment: Thankz @Dave. I found that. When I double click on that EXE file, that will directly show the output image. Thats fine. But my problem is :- how can I allow the user ( OR who is using my application) to upload the image by giving an **User Interface** and then I need to process that image in the backend using Visual Studio and OpenCV and then I need to give the output image back on to user in the **User Interface** itself? (Sorry for the mistakes, I am very new to Development and Stack Overflow too). Thankz.

Comment: Hi @Mants you will have to create a windows form application or a wpf application and create a user interface on there that implements your code from what I can understand. It is hard to explain to you without knowing what youve done so far. Maybe try looking up windows forms on MSDN that is a lot simpler than WPF, it sounds like your application can just have a form with a fileDialogue that passes the file path to your code. So you could also maybe look at something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666656/how-to-pass-file-path-to-a-variable-using-openfiledialog-control

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Publish from right-clicked project in Solution Explorer